# Loop through only text files present in directory to import data using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a below code which imports data from all files present in dir. I want to restrict data input to .txt files only. i.e. import from text files only. Any help.

```
    Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet() 
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim folder As folder
    Dim file As file
    Dim FileText As TextStream
    Dim TextLine As String
    Dim Items() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cl As Range
    ' Get a FileSystem object
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    ' get the directory you want
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder("D:\workdir\NX12IP25_RenewDaimler\textfiles\t")
    Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
    For Each file In folder.Files
        Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)
        Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
            TextLine = FileText.ReadLine
            Items = Split(TextLine, "|")
    cl.Value = folder & "\" & file.Name 
    For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
        cl.Offset(0, i + 1).Value = Items(i)
    Next
            Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
        Loop
        FileText.Close
    Next file
    Set FileText = Nothing
    Set file = Nothing
    Set folder = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `If` statement to check if last 4 characters are `.txt`. You can do it in two ways:

1) `If Right(file.Name, 4) = ".txt" Then ...`

or

2) using regular expressions: `If file.Name like "*.txt" Then ...`.

I prefer first solution, which is more efficient.

Checking this condition should be first operation you do inside your loop, so you would omit files that don't match our pattern (in this case, that aren't text files).

Comment: If you don't want to exclude .TXT files, use `If Right(LCase(file.Name), 4) = ".txt" Then...`

Comment: ok. I want to import from different folders but as I go importing it overwrites on previious data, how can start importing data from next blank row?

Comment: You have to determine last used row, which can be done using this code: `Cells(Rows.Count, column).End(xlUp).Row`, where `column` is the number of a column for which you want to determine last used row.

Comment: Can you please tell me where should I put it, I tried but getting error. I replaced column with 1.

Comment: I guess here: `cl.Offset(0, i + 1).Value = Items(i)`, so it becomes: `cl.Offset(0, lastRow + i + 1).Value = Items(i)`, where `lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`. But it's only guess. You should know best.

Answer (score 2):

Your main loop should look like this:

```
For Each file In folder.Files
    If Right(LCase(file.Name), 4) = ".txt" Then
        Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)
        Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
            TextLine = FileText.ReadLine
            Items = Split(TextLine, "|")
            cl.Value = folder & "\" & file.Name
            For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
                cl.Offset(0, i + 1).Value = Items(i)
            Next
            Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
        Loop
        FileText.Close
    End If
Next file
```

This will pick up files ending `.txt , .TXT , tXt` etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this either by checking the filename directly:

```
if LCase(Right(file.Name, 4) = ".txt") then
...
```

or let the fileSystemObject to the job for you

```
if LCase(fso.getextensionname(File.Path)) = "txt" then
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are limited to Text files, you can use the DIR function to specify the file filter.  Calling Dir the first time finds the first file that matches the search pattern.  Calling it again and again return the next files with the same pattern, so you can loop until it returns an empty string.

```
Dim file As String
file = Dir("D:\workdir\NX12IP25_RenewDaimler\textfiles\*.txt")
Do Until file = ""   ' Start the loop.
    Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)
    Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
        TextLine = FileText.ReadLine
        Items = Split(TextLine, "|")
        cl.Value = folder & "\" & file.Name 
        For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
            cl.Offset(0, i + 1).Value = Items(i)
        Next
        Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
    FileText.Close
    file = Dir()   ' Getting next entry.
Loop
```

Comment: That won't work. You can't use the `file.OpenAsTextStream` if `file` is a string.